# file not uploading in swift storage

Tags: file-upload, openstack-swift

I am using the formpost method of swift server to file upload. some time file get uploaded. But some time not.

On swift server log I am getting 499 httpcode. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: can any one help me on this issue......................:(

Answer (score 0):

499 Client Closed Request (Nginx)
Used in Nginx logs to indicate when the connection has been closed by client while the server is still processing its request, making server unable to send a status code back.

Its your client side issue which has a time limit for processing. If the time exceeds and upload has not happened it terminates the connection/upload process. It has nothing to do with Swift.

Hope it helps.